# Phonegap/Ionic angularJS native back button

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to add native back button to my app, on android its fine because you can use the android back button but on IOS i need to add a back button.

I am not using a `<nav>`, so i have added this to one of my pages :

```
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-arrow-left-c" ng-click="myGoBack()"></button>
```

And on my controller :

```
$scope.myGoBack = function() {
//$ionicHistory.goBack();
    console.log($ionicHistory);

  };
```

The result of `console.log($ionicHistory);` is `{}`... Does anyone know why it's empty?

Comment: Can you try $ionicHistory.viewHistory().histories

Comment: @Gandhi  { historyId: 'root',
     parentHistoryId: null,
     stack: [],
     cursor: -1 },
  ion1:
   { historyId: 'ion1',
     parentHistoryId: 'root',
     stack: [],
     cursor: -1 },
  ion6:
   { historyId: 'ion6',
     parentHistoryId: 'ion1',
     stack: [ [Object] ],
     cursor: 0 } }

Comment: this means that the history is tracked right..? you can use backView() or goBack() methods to navigate to previous page

Comment: They dont do anything

Comment: @Gandhi I dont think that is my history, i flick through all the pages and its always ion1, ion6, ion1 - they never change.

Comment: Are you using ionic side menu by any chance?

Comment: Ionic side menu has some issues with ionichistory as menu-close resets the history stack. Hope this link helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646894/ionic-history-stack-when-using-side-menu-and-tabs